# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource + The response had HTTP status code 401

Tags: javascript, angular, cors, preflight

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.1.253:8080/... No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

Pretty common error, with a great many possible solutions that haven't worked. I understand (I think) how CORS is supposed to work, and I don't see anything wrong with my HTTP headers, but it still doesn't work

From Chrome:

```
Request URL:http://192.168.1.253:8080/...
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:192.168.1.253:8080
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Response Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:x-requested-with,accept,content-
type,authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, PUT, PATCH, OPTIONS, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Max-Age:3600
Allow:GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, PATCH
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Date:Mon, 15 May 2017 21:50:55 GMT
Expires:0
Pragma:no-cache
Server:...
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
Request Headers
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:authorization,content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:192.168.1.253:8080
Origin:http://localhost:4200
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost:4200/...
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36
```

My understanding is the `OPTIONS` response needs the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header set and allow the method type and header values, which it does

Relevant angular below. I've done a fair number of different combinations of this with all sorts of different stuff in the header, but nothing works

```
private getObject<T>(path: string): Promise<T> {
    return this.http.get(SERVER_URL + path, this.authenticationToken())
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json() as T)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

private authenticationToken() : RequestOptions {
    let login = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('currentLogin'));
    if (login && login.authenticationToken) {
        let headers = new Headers({ 
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + login.authenticationToken,
            'Content-type': 'application/json', 
          });
        return new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    }
}
```

I got the feeling I'm missing something obvious but it's driving me nuts, any help is appreciated. Note this does work with a pre-existing Ember application so I don't think it's the server

Comment: When you try Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:4200 - explicitly put the url instead of * - does it work?

Comment: It's actually not your frontend or your requests. Your *backend* would need to be configured to allow CORS access. What you're getting back is actually a security measure by Chrome. I'm not saying it will solve all of your problems (401), but until you figure out how to configure CORS on your backend, this is a nice extension to tell Chrome to shut up: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

Comment: @Eeks33 afraid not

Comment: @joh04667 Thanks for the plugin, though i don't see how it could be the backend since it works with a different application

Comment: Since this is related to the backend server, you need to identify the technology it is running on and post/tag accordingly. Angular code is only client side requests and hence nothing to do with CORS

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> The response had HTTP status code 401.

401 indicates an authentication error. The error message in the question isn’t for a response from a preflight `OPTIONS` request. It instead seems to be for the actual `GET` request you’re trying to send.

So based on that error message, it seems the most likely scenario is that the browser’s preflight `OPTIONS` request succeeded but your `GET` request is not succeeding due to authentication failure.

So the server’s returning a 401 response/error page. And many/most web servers aren’t configured to send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header for error responses/pages. That’s the only reason you’re also getting a message about that header being missing.

But that missing header for the error response is not the cause of your problem; instead, the 401 is.

So it seems you probably want to figure out what’s causing the server to send a 401 response—why you’re getting an authentication failure. If you fix that it seems likely you’ll get a response from the server that includes the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header as expected.

Answer (score 9):

This is a typical error found when we work with Angular and Ionic, the problem appears because when your app loaded in a browser on your app loads all the content from an **origin** that comes from your local address `http://localhost:4200`, then when you want to make any AJAX request sent out to another host than  `localhost:4200`  the request  is called from an any point different from the **origin** its require a **CORS**(Cross Origin Resource Sharing) preflight request to see if it can access the resource.

The solution is use a Proxy To Backend, with this you can highjack certain urls and send them to a backend server. The implementation is easy:

1.- Create a file `proxy.conf.js` in the root folder of your project.

2.- Configure your proxy, inside your `proxy.conf.js` file put this, assuming your new host is in `http://localhost:3000`.

```js
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
    {
        context: [
            "/my",
            "/many",
            "/endpoints",
            "/i",
            "/need",
            "/to",
            "/proxy"
        ],
        target: "http://localhost:3000",
        secure: false
    }
]

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

3.- Modify your `package.json` file, inserting this `"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.js",`

4.- In your Service change a little the path of your request from this `http://localhost:3000/endpoints/any/path/that/you/use` to this `../endpoints/any/path/that/you/use`(assuming the another host is in `localhost:3000` and the context is `/endpoints`).

5.- Run angular since the root folder with:  `npm start` ; this execute  `ng serve`  with the proxy parameters.

If you need more  information about this please check the [Proxy to backend Angular Cli documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md)

Comment: Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question.*

Comment: Why this line has .js instead of .json ? - 3.- Modify your package.json file, inserting this "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.js",

Comment: This is a "js" file beacause the configuratiosn are exported with Module exports, node js is interpreting  this configuration as a constant while is running the "start" script.